# How do I add custom title and button to a header in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a simple page with list of students. Once I click on each student profile, I want to go to a new page, where the title of the page will be the name of the student and where I will have a button on the right. All of this should be done in the header. So I put the following code:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}
                  options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
 />
```

Which correctly displays the name of the student on the header. Then I wanted to add the button on the right and as written [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/) I changed my code to:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}
                  options={{ headerTitle: ({route}) => ({ title: route.params.name }),
                             headerRight: () => (
                                                <Button
                                                    onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                                                    title="Info"
                                                    color="#fff"
                                                  />),
                          }}
              />
```

And now I have the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')`
Can someone advice how to add both custom title and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass it like below

```
   options={({ route }) => ({
      title: route.params.name,
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
    })}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods by which you can set up the custom header

1. You can set up a custom button like this

   ```
    function LogoTitle() {
        return (
            <Image
               style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
               source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
            />
        );
    }

    function StackScreen() {
        return (
             <Stack.Navigator>
                 <Stack.Screen
                      name="Home"
                      component={HomeScreen}
                      options={{ headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> }}
                 />
             </Stack.Navigator>
        );
    }
   ```
2. You can hide the header by navigation

   ```
    options: {
        header: null,
    }
   ```

   and can also create custom header and import it to any component you can pass props from every component to that one custom header